# What is the "10/100/1000 BASE-T" laser/transceiver rate unit signifying?

Tags: lasers

I'm using a 10/100/1000 BASE-T fiber transceiver.

What does this mean?

Comment: Hi Rachael, welcome to engineering.SE.  Your question is rather vague to anyone who hasn't worked with this specific component.  Can you please add some more context to your question?  A link to the product you are talking about would be particularly helpful.

Comment: Are you asking about how the different transmission speeds might affect the technology used, or are you just looking for megabits/sec? And it shouldn't be "-T" if it is fiber, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 10/100/1000 refers to the transmission rate in megabits per second
= millions of bits per second.
Also may be shown as Mbps or Mb/s.

1000 Mb/s is a data rate typically achieved by modern LAN interfaces.

10 and 100 mb/s are the maximum rates achieved by older standards. 
A 10/100/1000 label is indicating that the device operates at the 1000 Mb/s rate where it is interfacing with equally capable equipment, but is also able to work at the 10 or 100 Mb/s rate and standards when the equipment it is interworking with is limited to those rates.

As hazzey notes, Base-T does not apply to fibre based equipment. It is a designation indicating that twisted pair is used as the transmission medium.
The original [**"Ethernet" LAN interface**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet)  (now part of IEEE 802.3-xxx) used coaxial cable and operated at 10 Mb/s.  When twisted pair interfaced  alternatives were introduced, the name BASE-T was introduced for twisted pair rather than coaxial cable interconnected equipment. 10 Base-T was used to designate 10 Mb/s twisted pair equipment.
"Just to confuse" designations 10Base5 and 10Base2 were designations relating to thin-coax 10 Mb/s Ethernet in the 1980s.

[Wikipedia - Gigabit Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet) - 
nominally re 1000 Mb/s systems but covers the historical development.

Ethernet [Fibre and twisted pair interfaces](https://www.perle.com/products/10-100-1000-media-converter.shtml)  exist but that is not what you are dealing with.

---

Related

[Ethernet over twisted pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_twisted_pair)

[Wikipedia - 10BASE2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE2)

[Wikipedia - 10BASE2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE5)

[10BASE2 & 10BASE5 eternet](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=ethernet&biw=1280&bih=789&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=URRtVYrrEqfGmQW7-4KQAg&ved=0CFAQsAQ#tbm=isch&q=ethernet+base-10) and[here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=ethernet&biw=1280&bih=789&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=URRtVYrrEqfGmQW7-4KQAg&ved=0CFAQsAQ#tbm=isch&q=ethernet+10base5) and [here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=ethernet&biw=1280&bih=789&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=URRtVYrrEqfGmQW7-4KQAg&ved=0CFAQsAQ#tbm=isch&q=ethernet+10base2)

[Ethernet](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=ethernet&biw=1280&bih=789&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=URRtVYrrEqfGmQW7-4KQAg&ved=0CFAQsAQ)